# Which version of record will be returned in read committed isolation of MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where my cluster is in **read committed isolation** mode and the use case is like below:

A select statement when executed takes around 1 minutes to run the query and get the response back.

During which updates (Committed) to data can happen during this time frame of 1 minute.

So my question is will I get the updated record in the response or the old record? I read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) and it's mentioned any phantom reads are allowed.

```
Using READ COMMITTED has additional effects(Reference MYSQL docs):
```

1. For UPDATE or DELETE statements, InnoDB holds locks only for rows
   that it updates or deletes. Record locks for nonmatching rows are
   released after MySQL has evaluated the WHERE condition. This greatly
   reduces the probability of deadlocks, but they can still happen.
2. For UPDATE statements, if a row is already locked, InnoDB performs a
   “semi-consistent” read, returning the latest committed version to
   MySQL so that MySQL can determine whether the row matches the WHERE
   condition of the UPDATE. If the row matches (must be updated), MySQL
   reads the row again and this time InnoDB either locks it or waits
   for a lock on it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way concurrent updates to data can modify a given query while it is executing. It's as if every query runs in its own REPEATABLE READ snapshot, even if your transaction is READ COMMITTED.

It will return rows that had been committed at the time the statement began executing. It will not include any rows committed after the statement began.

---

Re your comment:

No, there is no transaction isolation level that can change this. Even if you use READ UNCOMMITTED, a given query reads only rows that were committed at the time the query began executing.

If you want to query recent updates, you can only do it by starting a new query.

If you're concerned that you aren't getting notified about recent updates, then you need to optimize your query so it doesn't take 60 seconds to execute.

This is starting to sound like you're polling the database. Running frequent expensive queries to poll a database is an indication that perhaps you need to use a message queue instead.

---

Re your second comment:

Locking SQL statements, including UPDATE and DELETE and also locking SELECT statements do function like READ COMMITTED even when your transaction is REPEATABLE READ. Locking statements always read the most recent row that was committed *at the time the statement started*.

But they still cannot read new rows committed *after* the statement started. If for no other reason than they can't get the locks on those rows.

Your original question was about SELECT statements, and I assumed you meant non-locking SELECT (that is, without the options of FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE). Those SELECT statements also cannot view rows added after the SELECT started.

---

P.S. I have never found a good use of READ UNCOMMITTED for any purpose.

Comment: what if i want those changes as well, shall i use read uncommitted?It will allow dirty reads @Bill

Comment: make sense to me, i have edited my post and have added the statement where i got confused actually. Can you please clarify on that as well? @Bill?

Comment: "Even if you use READ UNCOMMITTED, a given query reads only rows that were committed at the time the query began executing." This is apparently [not true](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/305258) (and poorly documented in the official docs). Even worse, in my tests, a `select *` in `READ UNCOMMITTED` will see rows that were inserted after the query was started, as well as rows that were deleted after the query was started.

Comment: @MikaelF All the more reason to never use READ UNCOMMITTED!

Comment: @BillKarwin The one use case I've seen for it is to debug integration tests, by setting a breakpoint in the middle of a transaction and logging onto the DB to see what's happening.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking of never using read uncommitted as part of application code. But I see the use of what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

By default, INNOBD will lock the tables during processing, but there are ways to do an UNLOCKED SELECT. In that case, it will run on a versioned snapshot of the table, so any COMMIT during the processing won't alter the result.

For more information:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

In all cases, the ACID property of databases will always prevent unstable functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: what if i want those changes as well, shall i use read uncommitted?It will allow dirty reads

Comment: Read_uncommitted allows dirty reads, but that's not what you want (you want commited transactions done in parallel). Plus it is not ACID compliant and some databases will outright refuse to do it. It's difficult to say if it will work in your case, and I wouldn't recommend it anyway.